# Date time in Python (strftime)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-requests

Time data `'Jun 02 16:06:57.451'` does not match format `'%m %d %H:%M:%S.%f'`

```
datetime.strptime(input_time, "%m %d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're probably interested in this : https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Try this instead: `datetime.strptime('Jun 02 16:06:57.451',"%b %d %H:%M:%S.%f")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the format to exactly the way you're supplying the date:

```
 datetime.strptime('Jun 02 16:06:57.451',"%b %d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

`datetime.datetime(1900, 6, 2, 16, 6, 57, 451000)`

Format types are here: [Formats](http://strftime.org/)